# Can moderators see who upvoted/downvoted a specific question?

Tags: support, voting, moderator-abilities, privacy

Can moderators see who upvoted/downvoted a specific question? How about who upvoted a specific comment?

Note that I'm asking for no reason besides to satisfy my own curiosity.

Answer (score 134, accepted):

No. Moderators can't see who voted on a specific question (or answer). Moderators can only see [some aggregate data to help identify voting fraud](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/218120).

Stack Exchange Employees can, but from our understanding, generally do not unless there is cause to.  The information isn't exposed in any easy fashion internally (on purpose), and as such requires going to the database and running a query to look for the source of a particular post's votes.

Moderators are elected by the community and [can be found on this page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/site-moderators).

Stack Exchange employees can also have diamonds next to their name, and they generally disclose that they are employees in their "About Me" box. Even if they don't they have the "Staff" indicator on their profile.

Comment: I always thought that they could :).

Comment: But Shog sees all.

Comment: @bjb568 - Shog isn't a moderator, he's an *employee*.

Comment: In the case of Shog, most regular site visitors have probably figured that out. But otherwise, if you see a diamond next to somebody's name, you really have to go to the profile page to see if they are employees or elected moderators. I believe the employees are required to disclose their status in the About Me box.

Comment: To be clear, both moderators and employees have access to tools that will identify *voting patterns.*  We don't really concern ourselves with individual votes.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Is there any interesting statistical information about typical voting patterns on SO that can be revealed to the public? I just like statistics a lot.

Comment: Might be worth adding that, I believe, the tools employees have to reveal who voted on what are not available for their own posts.  At that point they'd have to query the db to see.

Comment: @Trilarion you can discern a lot of statistics from the [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com/), but the stats that moderators have access to cannot be discussed privately as it would violate the [moderator agreement](https://meta.stackexchange.com/legal/moderator-agreement).

Comment: This post (admittedly from 2011) says that developers can *easily* see who voted on posts ***that aren't their own***. http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/90758/163863. Note developers != mods, and != community managers.