# How can I know who has upvoted and who downvoted?

Tags: support, voting

A few days back I asked one question. A few users upvoted it and few downvoted it. But I have no clue who has voted in my question.

Is there a way to know that who has upvoted or who has downvoted my question or answer?

Comment: That's the whole point. So you can't go and attack the downvoters.

Comment: 1. Why do you want to know? 2. [Why take it personally?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/269461/2564301)

Comment: Invest in a good crystal ball.

Comment: voting is [anonymous by design](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/12984/165773) - whole system is carefully built and tuned to protect voters from being guessed that they vote at all, even when someone else wants to know

Comment: If you apply an up/down vote yourself, you will know who did it.

Comment: Me.  It was me.  They were all me.  I am spartacus.

Comment: see also: [Can moderators see who upvoted/downvoted a specific question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275052/can-moderators-see-who-upvoted-downvoted-a-specific-question)

Answer (score 24):

You can't. And shouldn't.

Votes are anonymous so that you (the recipient of votes) are voting based on the *post* and not the *person*.

Answer (score 18):

You can't.

Voting is secret.

Not even moderators know who voted and which way.

Comment: who is moderator?

Comment: @Rahul The irony here is a bit striking. Hint: They have diamonds next to their user names

Comment: ok got u, so no one can see the voter details.

Comment: @Rahul see [Who are the diamond moderators, and what is their role?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/75189/165773)

Comment: @Emrakul haha.  As a 1k user I can see there are no downvotes on this post.  But that still doesn't tell me if you actually upvoted.  Hmm.  Now whether to start serial voting for/against you.  (I'm joking of course)